# How to run a command on multiple hosts in Ruby using NEXEC

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, rubygems, server

I want to run a command on multiple servers using net/ssh gem in Ruby.
All the host names are saved in a file, from the saved file I am reading host names one by one and want to  execute the command by using NEXEC.

Eg: For single host I ran this command

```
$NEXEC="/data/bladelogic-7.3/bin/nexec"

$INSTANCE=`#{$NEXEC} hostname ls -ltr mypath`
```

How can do it for multiple hostnames by using NEXEC

**Below is my code:**

```
require 'rubygems'
require 'net/ssh'
require 'net/ssh/multi'
puts "Enter the username"
@username=gets.chomp

File.open("path for multiple host file names","r") do |s|
s.each_line do |line|
Net::SSH.start(line.chomp,@username) do |ssh|
result=ssh.exec!("ls -ltr")
result1=`#{$NEXEC} line ls -ltr`
puts result
end
end
end
```

**Error:**

Error accessing host line: Remote host is unknown

Answer (score 0):

This is long over due but I just had a similar problem, lets start with this:

- You indentation is awful, two spaces per indent according to the
  [Ruby Styleguide](https://github.com/bbatsov/ruby-style-guide)
- The `net/ssh` gem also needs a password argument that looks like this `:password => 'your_pass_here'`
- In Ruby there's a library called `etc` which you can automatically get the username that's logged in, that way you don't have to enter the username, only the password
- Ruby has an easier way to read files using `File.read`

Suggested edits:

```
require 'rubygems'
require 'net/ssh'
require 'etc'

print "Enter password: "
@password = gets.chomp #<= You can get rid of the echo so they can't see your keystrokes if you want, see below
@username = Etc.getlogin

File.read(path/to/file.file) do |s|
  s.each_line do |line|
    Net::SSH.start(line.chomp, @username, :password => @password) do |ssh|
      result = ssh.exec!("ls -la")
      result1=`#{$NEXEC} line ls -ltr`
      puts result
    end
  end
end
```

To get rid of the echo of the password, one way to do it is with a system call:

```
system "stty -echo"
@password = gets.chomp
system "stty echo"
```

***ALWAYS*** recall the echo, or you won't be able to see anything typed within the program.

Comment: Be very careful using `read`. It's not scalable and can take a program to its knees if you read a file bigger than your system can handle.